# The right homotopy class and cofibrant replacement

Tags: model-categories

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map in a model category. Let us denote $Qf$ "the" map it induces on the cofibrant replacements of $X$ and $Y$. How can I show that if $Y$ is fibrant, the right homotopy class of $Qf$ is determined by the right homotopy class of $f$?